# No DNS layer using scapy from python 2.6

Tags: python, dns, scapy

I use python 2.6 with `scapy`. My little program tries to print response details of the `DNS` , `DNSQR` and `DNSRR` layers after running `sr1` command. The problem is that the packet which is returned from `sr1` command does not include these layers, but instead includes Raw layer above the `UDP` layer.

On the other hand, the `DNS` packet I created (in the code - `dns_packet`) includes all these layers!!!

The question is - why I don't get these layers (and only Raw layer) from `sr1` command? And what should I do to get these layers from `sr1` command (in order to print `DNSRR.rdata` for example)?

Appreciate your response, thank you and best regards, Eldad.

Here is my code:

```
from scapy.all import *

host_name = raw_input("please enter host name:")

while host_name != "exit":

    print host_name

    dns_packet = IP(dst='8.8.8.8')/UDP(sport=24601,dport=53)/DNS(qdcount=1,qd=DNSQR(qname=host_name))

    print dns_packet.show()

    response_packet = sr1(dns_packet)

    print response_packet.show()

    host_name = raw_input("please enter host name:")
```

Comment: When I execute your code, I do get a response that includes the `DNS` layer. Can you please update your question to show what exactly you get in `response_packet`?

Comment: Instead of DNS layer, i get a Raw layer

Comment: Instead of a DNS layer i get a Raw layer with data, which probably includes the DNS's layer information as a data. I guess it means that scapy can't recognize my DNS layer. When i run the same commands directly from scapy it shows the DNS layer with no problem. I recently found also some students who have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also tryed to solve this problem - after many hours i found out that its a known bug (python-scapy bug)

the fix:

1) go to  python folder then Lib\site-packages\scapy\

2) open the file pton_ntop.py and reach to line 66  (yes, believe me ... its not a jock)

3) add socket.  after the return, so the line will be like this:
    return socket.inet_ntoa(addr)

4) save and close

5) delete the file  pton_ntop.pyc

for me it worked ..  Bye Bye